# Updating Child Nodes in Firebase. Why is only one reference being updated and not both?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users in my firebase database.

[image: Here is what my firebase database looks like]

I am trying to add a friend request feature. Upon the friend request button being touched, I want both users' friends list in my database to be modified accordingly

For some reason

```
Ref.child("users").child(currentUserUid!).child("Friends").updateChildValues([userClickedOnId! : false])
```

accurately updates the current user's friend list. However, the first statement ,

```
Ref.child("users").child(userClickedOnId!).child("Friends").updateChildValues([currentUserUid : false])
```

does not update the clicked on user's friend list in the firebase database.

I have added print statements, tried one statement at a time. The statements that start with Ref. are nearly identical so why is only the second statement where I modify the currentUser's friend's list working?

```
 @IBAction func funcconnectRequestButtonDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let userClickedOnId = uid
        let Ref = Database.database().reference()

        Ref.child("users").child(userClickedOnId!).child("Friends").updateChildValues([currentUserUid : false])
        Ref.child("users").child(currentUserUid!).child("Friends").updateChildValues([userClickedOnId! : false])
}
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind are security rules. Do you have security rules that allow a user to only write their own data? If so, you should also find an error message in the client logs for the write operation that isn't working.

Comment: I have both my read and write security settings set to true

Comment: @LynnO'Brian simply on friend request create a separate node  pending requests  and on acceptance of that request add move that node to friend list.?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another node friendRequests and inside this node you may have childs with keys userUIDs and data `senderUID1 : datelong, senderUID2 : datelong` and simply listen for this in your application dbref.child('friendRequests/' + userUID).addChildEventListener and you gonna obtain every friend request that already exists + listen for new requests.
Let the user with the parentID be able to write the value of senderUUID as true or "accepted", w/e fits you.
Then create a cloud function (trigger) to listen onUpdate on `friendRequests/{userUID}/{senderUID}` and if the value is true add to both friend lists the ids of each user. If it's false just delete this reference.
Since writing all this code according to your data structure will take huge amount of time, I am going to give you already existing code doing just that but you have to rewrite it:
These are the rules:

```
"friendList": {
  "$uid":{
    ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
    "$friendUID": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && data.exists() && newData.val() == false"
    }
  }
},

"friendRequest": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
    "$senderUID": {
      ".write" : "$senderUID === auth.uid && $senderUID != $uid && !data.exists() && root.child('userInfo').child($uid).exists() && !root.child('blockList').child($uid).child($senderUID).exists() && !root.child('blockList').child($senderUID).child($uid).exists() && !root.child('friendList').child($uid).child($senderUID).exists() && !root.child('friendList').child($senderUID).child($uid).exists() && !root.child('friendRequest').child($senderUID).child($uid).exists()",
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['message', 'date'])",
      "message": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 51 && newData.val().length > 0"
      },
      "date": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() == now" // ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      },
      "accepted": {
        ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid && $uid != $senderUID && (newData.val() == true || newData.val() == false) && !data.exists() && root.child('friendRequest').child($uid).child($senderUID).exists()"
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": false
      }

    }
  }
},

"blockList":{
  "$uid":{
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    "$blockUID": {
      ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid && $uid != $blockUID && ( ((!data.exists() && newData.val() == true) || (data.exists() && !newData.exists())) ) && root.child('userInfo').child($blockUID).exists()"
    }
  }
},
```

The rules are not very good as you can see but you can rewrite them to fit your case and remove some useless code as far as I can see.
Now the cloud functions:

```
exports.dbWriteOnFriendRequestChoice = functions.database.ref('/friendRequest/{receiverid}/{senderid}/accepted').onWrite((change, context) => {
    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    const writtenContent = change.after.val(); // true || false
    const receiverid = context.params.receiverid;
    const senderid = context.params.senderid;

    if(writtenContent) {
        const promiseAccepted1 = admin.database().ref('/friendList/' + senderid + '/' + receiverid).set(true);
    const promiseAccepted2 = admin.database().ref('/friendList/' + receiverid + '/' + senderid).set(true);
    const promiseRefused = admin.database().ref('/friendRequest/' + receiverid + '/' + senderid).remove();
        return Promise.all([promiseAccepted1, promiseAccepted2, promiseRefused]);
    } else {
        const promiseRefused = admin.database().ref('/friendRequest/' + receiverid + '/' + senderid).remove();
        return Promise.all([promiseRefused]);
    }
});

exports.dbWriteOnBlock = functions.database.ref('/blockList/{useruid}/{blockuid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    //const writtenContent = change.after.val(); // true || false
    const useruid = context.params.useruid;
    const blockuid = context.params.blockuid;

    const promiseFriendList1 = admin.database().ref('/friendList/' + useruid + '/' + blockuid).remove();
    const promiseFriendList2 = admin.database().ref('/friendList/' + blockuid + '/' + useruid).remove();
    return Promise.all([promiseFriendList1, promiseFriendList2]);
    /*const promiseUnblock = admin.database().ref('/blockList/' + useruid + '/' + blockuid).remove();

    if(writtenContent) {
        return Promise.all([promiseFriendList1, promiseFriendList2]);
    } else {
        return Promise.all([promiseUnblock]);
    }*/
});

exports.dbWriteOnUnfriend = functions.database.ref('/friendList/{useruid}/{frienduid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    const writtenContent = change.after.val(); // true || false
    const useruid = context.params.useruid;
    const frienduid = context.params.frienduid;

    if(!writtenContent) {
        const promiseReove1 = admin.database().ref('/friendList/' + useruid + '/' + frienduid).remove();
        const promiseReove2 = admin.database().ref('/friendList/' + frienduid + '/' + useruid).remove();
        return Promise.all([promiseReove1, promiseReove2]);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

You can remove the blocking and do your thing. This works on 100% because I have tested it in this app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGCNsD_eeSA

Comment: Thank you kindly for this helpful feedback! I think I was able to solve my issue.